# Group by and sum multiple columns

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

I have data  in multiple columns, and I'm trying to find day-over-day growth rates across columns. I know this can be done with a simple window function. However, I'm also trying to figure out growth rates for particular column variables with 'ALL' in the remaining columns.

| Date | Region | Territory | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2022 | US | North | 10 |
| 1/1/2022 | EU | West | 11 |
| 1/1/2022 | US | South | 13 |
| 1/1/2022 | EU | East | 14 |
| 1/2/2022 | US | North | 20 |
| 1/2/2022 | EU | West | 33 |
| 1/2/2022 | US | South | 26 |
| 1/2/2022 | EU | East | 42 |

Expected output is:

| Date | Region | Territory | Growth Rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/2/2022 | US | ALL | 100% |
| 1/2/2022 | EU | ALL | 200% |
| 1/2/2022 | ALL | North | 100% |
| 1/2/2022 | ALL | East | 200% |
| 1/2/2022 | ALL | West | 100% |
| 1/2/2022 | ALL | South | 200% |
| 1/2/2022 | US | North | 100% |
| 1/2/2022 | US | South | 100% |
| 1/2/2022 | EU | East | 200% |
| 1/2/2022 | EU | West | 200% |

Edit: I'm building this out in Athena which uses Presto SQL.

Comment: It is more likely to put CREATE TALBE and INSERT script under your question instead of image; in order to easily use your sample data.

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: Sounds like you need a rollup or grouping sets. Your expected output only has date 1/2/2022? You are yet to even tag your RDBMS as already asked, if you post a question you [really should revisit every so often](https://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive) to see if someone has commented and asked for clarification

Comment: Just added - using Presto SQL.